# How to tell if a cider is finished without hydrometer

Tags: cider, wine, airlock, hydrometer

EDITED

I have a cider that I have made following the steps on [CraigTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=La38oQjdyPw) for his Hard Apple Cider. The only difference is that I have used Champagne yeast and the batch is 22L. I know you are all going to say to check my hydrometer reading but unfortunately I smashed the hydrometer before I could take the initial reading. The airlock still has activity and is still bubbling after 18 days. It is bubbling strongly every 13 seconds. How will I know when it is done. Should I wait until the airlock has no activity at all?

Recipe here:

21L Juice (7bottles)

Yeast Nutrient (Boil up raisins (that don’t have sulphite on them) and small amount of water, mash up the raisins and simmer)

10- 14Cup’s corn sugar or dextrose (the more sugar the more kick it will have)

1 Lalvin EC1118 Yeast

Steps

1. Boil up yeast nutrient and mash up raisins
2. Take out a little juice from the bottle and add sugar.
3. Shake out the sugar(even do this for the fermenter batch as it saves time and stiring)
4. Put in the yeast nutrient(make sure that it isn’t still too hot) and shake the bottle
5. Add the yeast and shake the bottle
   a.  If you are making a fermenter size batch then pour it all in the fermenter
6. Leave that until the fermenter has stopped bubbling and leave for a few days.

Ok I have done a small scale test. I have had 1.5L of juice and 1cup sugar(200grams)
The reading was 1.092. This test does not include the boiled up rasins.

Ok so another reading has been taken. This is 1.000

Comment: Can you put the general recipe you used? ie 6L apple juice, 100 grams white/brown sugar, etc

Comment: Added the recipe and steps

Comment: Ok I have taken my reading after buying a hydrometer. It is 1.045. I will take another reading in two days time and see how it goes. Is there anyway to calculate the alcohol content without the first reading?

Comment: If you had weighed the sugar instead of measuring it, I could have made a ballpark calculation about your OG.  But I don't know how much a cup of sugar weighs. At the current gravity, I'd say it's nowhere near done.  A final gravity for cider is usually well under 1.010, usually closer to 1.000.

Comment: OK thanks @DennyConn When I took the hydrometer reading it surley tasted nice. No off flavors or anything. Crisp and dry but nice. Do you think that I leave it until it stops bubbling or until the FG is under 1.010

Comment: Always trust the gravity reading, not the bubbles.  FWIW, the OG of most apple juice is right around 45 without adding additional sugar.  The sugar you added has about 45 points/lb./gal.  For the sake of ease, let's round your batch to 5 gal.  It's close to that.  That means that with apple juice alone you would have an OG of about 1.045.  Like I said, I have no idea how much your sugar weighed.  Let's assume it was 2 lb.  That would add another 18 points to your OG, making it around 1.063.  If it's only at 1.045 now, your fermentation is going very slowly.

Comment: I usually give my ciders several months in the fermenter, but that's more for clarity and flavor.  Your fermentation seems to be going very slowly.  I recommend you weigh 10-14 cups of sugar and see just how much you put in.

Comment: Thanks. I might even do a small scale test with some leftover juice and sugar I have. I will let you know later today

Comment: @DennyConn See the question for the test results I have and the weight of 1 cup of sugar

Comment: How warm was the nutrient mixture when you added the yeast? If it was too hot (> ~130 F.) you can kill the yeast.

Comment: It had cooled for over half an hour and was mixed in with the juice and sugar for 20 minutes before the yeast was added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with champagne yeast, fermentation shouldn't take more than a couple of days to complete fully.  At the eighteen day mark, what you're seeing is degassing of the cider, where residual CO2 from the fermentation is escaping the liquid, not fermentation.  At this point, your cider has complete fermentation, and should be aged as necessary before being bottled/kegged off for consumption.

Of course, the only way to verify this is to purchase another hydrometer, and take readings.  If the measurements don't change over the course of 2-4 days, you'll know that the fermentation has completed, but judging by your disclaimer in your question, you already know that.

Update: After seeing that your gravity is at 1.045 after 18+ days, your cider is not degassing, but still fermenting.  As far why it is still fermenting after 18 days, I would guess that raisins did not provide enough nutrient to the yeast.  Cider by itself lacks a lot of essential nutrients needed by the yeast to ferment fully, and quickly.  At this point, I would recommend making the purchase and getting some [commercial yeast nutrient](http://www.wyeastlab.com/hb_productdetail.cfm?ProductID=15).  There are many different brands of it, most of which are very effective.

If you cannot get any yeast nutrient, your best bet is to be patient, and wait until you hit a terminal gravity where the gravity stays steady for a couple of days.  At that point it has fully fermented.  With a high gravity of ~1.092 (according to small scale), you are going to want to let it age for some time before consuming, so it doesn't sound like you should be in any hurry to see it ferment out all the way, so long as it does.

Comment: THIS^^^^  You can guess based on the signs, but the only way to KNOW is to take readings.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I will take some readings and see what happens. Is it bad to leave it in the fermenter degassing? What effect will Degassing have on the brew?

Comment: Degassing can take weeks.  There's nothing to worry about, it's natural, and means nothing regarding the quality of the cider.  Depending on how strong it is, you may want to let it go for quite some time.  You can bottle it off/consume it at any point, degassing or not.

Comment: Just a couple of days to ferment fully? I've used champagne yeast for many meads and a couple of cysers (which is very similar to cider) and based on hydrometer readings, fermentation can take between 14 and 20 days. I think the *shortest* I've had was 8 days when I started using nutrients (I didn't use any in the past), and it was also a bit warmer than usual inside. What kinds of nutrients are required to complete fermentation in just a couple of days?

Comment: While I have no experience with meads (or cysers), I have heard that they can take significantly longer than beer or ciders to complete fermentation.  I've also heard that staggered yeast nutrient additions over the days can work to shorten the fermentation schedule and produce a cleaner fermented mead.  I cannot recall where I read the latter suggestion, so I'd take that with a grain of salt.  Bear in mind we're talking about two different types of liquids being fermented.

Comment: @Scott: The cyser I've made sounds very close to OP's recipe for cider, except I used honey instead of their corn syrup. I've never tried staggered yeast, so I guess that might work, but I'd still be suprised if it finished in under a week with the OP's given original reading of 1.092

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that he updated his question with the small-scale OG.  I've never used raisins as a substitute for yeast nutrient, but it has me questioning how effective it is.  Even by your measure where you've experienced fermentations between 14-20 days, he's at the higher end of that with 18+ days, so that tells me a lack of sufficient nutrients for the yeast.

Comment: @Scott I also took a hydrometer reading yesterday which was 1.045. I will take another reading tomorrow to see if there is any change. There are also some more comments under the question which may have some information useful for your diagnosis.

Comment: Hi @Scott thanks for the updated answer. I will try to get some proper yeast nutrient and see what that does unless anyone else say otherwise. What is your reasoning for "letting it age for some time before consuming"? I will be marking your answer as correct unless someone can give me a better answer.

Comment: You certainly don't *need* to age the cider for a long time, but you may find that the flavor will improve with age.  A lot of high gravity beverages (be it ciders, meads, even beers) tend to take a bit longer to hit their peak flavor than their lower gravity counter-parts.  What I'd recommend as a little experiment for you to try is to mimic your recipe several more times in the coming months (with proper nutrient additions, of course), and then trying a vertical tasting of what it's like at certain months of the aging process.  You'll notice the vast difference in flavor.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good idea @Scott I will definitely give that a go. I will post the findings in the question when I do the tastings. Thanks for your help